# If I use Javascript for my scripts in Unity, will I be able to export the project to Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, unityscript

As above. Will I be able to publish the app to Windows Phone which is using Javascript inside Unity project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unity is a **cross platform engine** so what you code inside it can be used **all** across platforms . no matter what language you use

Comment: Do you have personal experience or do you just think that it should work? (See my answer) I also thought it should work, but I googled because of this question and started to have doubts.